# Cannot access org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet when compiling into WAR file

Tags: java, war, jdeveloper

I am trying to compile my project into WAR file but hit the error mentioned. I already added the jar files on the libraries and classpath. Any idea on how to fix this?

Comment: Which exact JDeveloper version do you use?

Please show us how you have defined the library and where you have added it.

Comment: Hello, I updated the library to the latest version and the error did not appear. Thank you btw